# Problems with creating a Dict with label and a list of corresponding tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, label, data-science

I would like to read a csv data which contains list entries with a label and two corresponding data points. All in All, there are three labels N,M,U.
I would like to create a Dict with a key for each of the label and all the corresponding data points in a list as value for the key. I tried with the below code, but have the problem that it returns a Dict with {"N":[all datapoint]}, so it assigns every data point to the label N and doesn't create a new key for M and U.
Does anybody see the problem here?

```
    with open('./data.csv', 'r') as i:
    D = {}
    
    for line in i: 
            datatuple = tuple(line[2:-1].split(","))
            floattuple = (float(datatuple[0])),float(datatuple[1])
            label = line[:1]
            if label in D:
                D[label].append(floattuple)
            else:
                D[label] = [floattuple]
            
return D
```

Example data from the csv:

[image: CSV data]
Thanks!

Comment: Please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Is there a possibility that I can attach the CSV file?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the exact reason Python's `dict` has the [`.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method.

First, let's define a generator to generate some random data

```
In [28]: def lines():
    ...:     from random import random, randrange
    ...:     for _ in range(12):
    ...:         key = {0:'M', 1:'N', 2:'U'}[randrange(3)]
    ...:         yield ','.join((
    ...:             key,
    ...:             "%+5.3f"%(random()*10-5),
    ...:             "%+5.3f"%(random()*10-5)
    ...:         ))
```

Then, just as you read lines from a file, we read lines from the generator and update our dictionary, using the `setdefault()` method that, if the item is new, provides a default value, here an empty list, that you can immediately use to append the *x, y* point (I have placed some `print`s into the code so that you can check its correctness)

```
In [29]: d = {}
    ...:
    ...: for line in lines():
    ...:     print(line)
    ...:     key, x, y = line.split(',')
    ...:     d.setdefault(key, []).append((float(x), float(y)))
    ...: print(*((k+': '+', '.join(str(t) for t in d[k])) for k in d), sep='\n')
M,-0.141,+1.755
M,+0.088,+3.354
N,+3.295,-3.847
U,+1.771,-3.268
M,-4.215,-4.499
U,-2.647,+1.218
U,-0.039,-0.357
U,+3.311,-3.312
N,-0.015,+2.039
N,-0.157,+3.319
N,-4.088,-0.914
U,+4.266,+4.863
M: (-0.141, 1.755), (0.088, 3.354), (-4.215, -4.499)
N: (3.295, -3.847), (-0.015, 2.039), (-0.157, 3.319), (-4.088, -0.914)
U: (1.771, -3.268), (-2.647, 1.218), (-0.039, -0.357), (3.311, -3.312), (4.266, 4.863)

In [30]:
```

Comment: Good choice on the`setdefault`. Definitely better than my `D[label] = D.get(label, list()) + [datatuple]`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```py
#  i = ["N,1,2", "U,3,4", "U,5,6"]

D = {}
with open('./data.csv', 'r') as i:
    for line in i: 
        line_list = line.split(",")
        datatuple = tuple(map(float, line_list[1:]))
        label = line_list[0]

        D[label] = D.get(label, list()) + [datatuple]

return D
```

Using the example data `i = ["N,1,2", "U,3,4", "U,5,6"]` this results in `{'N': [(1.0, 2.0)], 'U': [(3.0, 4.0), (5.0, 6.0)]}`.

An arguably better option would be to use [pandas `read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). Depending on the size of your data, this will also be much faster:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(3)

# Create example data (same structure as in the OP) and write to disk
pd.DataFrame({"label": np.random.choice(["M", "N", "U"], 10),
              "x": map("{:.3f}".format, np.random.normal(size=10)),
              "y": map("{:.3f}".format, np.random.normal(size=10))}
                       ).to_csv("./data.csv", header=False, index=False)

# read data to dataframe, convert to tuple, groupby and convert to dict 
D = (pd.read_csv("./data.csv", header=None, names=["label", "x", "y"])
         .set_index("label")
         .apply(tuple, axis=1)
         .groupby("label")
         .apply(list)
         .to_dict())

# Output: 
{'M': [(-0.581, -1.69), (-1.147, -1.73), (-0.611, 0.696), (-1.19, 0.565)],
 'N': [(-0.152, -0.349),
  (0.872, 0.48),
  (-0.016, -0.29600000000000004),
  (-2.1590000000000003, -0.86)],
 'U': [(0.278, 0.7559999999999999), (1.167, -0.42)]}
```

Some rounding errors occur when reading the csv file (`0.29600000000000004` etc.).

Comment: Hmm, still get the same output which assigns every data tuple to N...

Comment: I added the output I obtain when using my small example. It should work. However, I suggest you use pandas. Explicit loops are to be avoided in python. See my added example.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it now.